# Can I refer to an object's attribute by string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

If I have a ruby class called Node:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  attr_reader :key
  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end
  def [](letter)
    if letter == 'a'
      return self.a
    elsif letter == 'b'
      return self.b
    elsif letter == 'c'
      return self.c
    end
  end
end
```

How can I optimize `def [](letter)` so I won't have repetitive code? More specifically, how can I access an attribute of an object (that is a ruby symbol `:a`, `:b`, or `:c`) by using a corresponding string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `send`, which invokes a method dynamically on the caller, in this case `self`:

```
class Node
  def [](key)
    key = key.to_sym
    send(key) if respond_to?(key)
  end
end
```

Note that we check that `self` has the appropriate method before calling it. This avoids getting a `NoMethodError` and instead results in `node_instance[:banana]` returning `nil`, which is appropriate given the interface.

By the way, if this is the majority of the behavior of your `Node` class, you may simply want to use an OpenStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'
node_instance = OpenStruct.new(a: 'Apple', b: 'Banana')
node_instance.a    #=> 'Apple'
node_instance['b'] #=> 'Banana'
node_instance.c = 'Chocolate'
node_instance[:c]  #=> 'Chocolate'
```

Comment: You don't need `key = key.to_sym`.

Comment: @sawa Anymore, but probably not necessary for an answer. I guess 1.8.7  is pretty out of use now.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I can't parse your comment. Is your comment for or against my comment?

Comment: @sawa `to_sym` was necessary < Ruby 2.0 because `send` and `respond_to?` only accepted a symbol.

Comment: Right. But I don't get why you have "but". Do you mean "so"? And why you said "for an answer". But it's okay. :)